Only registered number can access verify otp page. FlutterFlow
firestore rules image
I think issue in firestore rules. I'm trying to solve from below points - cause getting

Error: [firebase_auth/admin-restricted-operation] This operation is restricted to administrators only.

firebase auth imagefirestore data image
Desire : want otp only from firestore exists phone number.
I am able to access otp but only from 2 numbers who have previously signed when no condition applied in flutterflow. But after condition i m not getting otp.
Here I am getting captch icon after i enter firestore saved phone number and click send otp . with no smack bar mwssage.

The error message pretty explicitly says that it's caused by Firebase Authentication, so it seems very unlikely your Firestore rules are the cause here.
